# Perl, print header with multiple stylesheet and media queries

Tags: perl, header, media-queries

I'm trying to print the header of a webpage through perl using CGI.

I need to obtain something like

```
<link href="css/mob.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width:749px)" />
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:750px)" />
<link href="css/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

but I'm having problems with the "media" attribute.
I tried with

```
-style=> {
   -src=> [
      '../css/main.css',
      '../css/print.css',
      '../css/mob.css'
   ],
   -media=> [
      'only screen and (min-width:750px)',
      'print',
      'only screen and (max-width:749px)'
   ]
 }
```

but the result is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css" media="ARRAY(0x1ae6bb0)"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/print.css" media="ARRAY(0x1ae6bb0)"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/mob.css" media="ARRAY(0x1ae6bb0)"/>
```

(if I use a single media parameter, everything is ok, but I need a media for each css).
If instead I use multiple -style writings they overwrite each others.

What about the <--if--> part? I suppose I should write arbitrary content (thus solving also the previous problem) but I can't get it to compile.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clearly you are using the array in the wrong way. You are accessing and printing the ref value (i.e. `$ar`). To access correctly you have to do something like `@{$ar}`, supposing that `$ar` is your ref. Lear more at [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Comment: I'm not using explicitely arrays, I'm using the function start_html

Comment: How are you passing actual parameters to it?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/t4aLj0SP (anyway I managed to cheat and print the media. It's horrible but it works)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-media` option only accepts a single string, but you're passing an array reference. The [CGI documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#LIMITED-SUPPORT-FOR-CASCADING-STYLE-SHEETS) describes how to generate more complicated `<link>` tags using the `Link` function:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw(Link);

my $q = CGI->new;

my @head = (
    Link({ -rel => 'stylesheet', -type => 'text/css', -src => '../css/main.css',
           -media => 'only screen and (min-width:750px)' }),
    Link({ -rel => 'stylesheet', -type => 'text/css', -src => '../css/print.css',
           -media => 'print' }),
    Link({ -rel => 'stylesheet', -type => 'text/css', -src => '../css/mob.css',
           -media => 'only screen and (max-width:749px)' }),
);

print $q->header,
      $q->start_html({ -head => \@head }),
      $q->h1('foo'),
      $q->end_html;
```

#### Output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:750px)" src="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" media="print" src="../css/print.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width:749px)" src="../css/mob.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>foo</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that even though CGI.pm *can* generate HTML, it's a big pain and not easy to maintain. I'd recommend using a templating system like [Template Toolkit](http://www.template-toolkit.org/) instead.

Comment: I used this one, thanks. Can I output arbitrary content this way?

Comment: nevermind, it took a bit to understand that Link it's only for "link" tags

Comment: You can add arbitrary *attributes* to a `<link>` tag this way, e.g. `Link({ -foo => 'bar'})` outputs `<link foo="bar" />`. To output arbitrary *content* of *any* type, just use `print`, e.g. `print q{<non_standard_tag>some content</non_standard_tag>};` (or better yet, a templating system).

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. The HTML generation methods in CGI.pm have been generally accepted as a bad idea for fifteen years. Use a [templating system](http://tt2.org/) instead.